# shuffling multiple choice array in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift4, shuffle

could someone explain me how to shuffle an array which contains several items, like this:

```
var answers = [["A","B","C"], ["D","E","F"], ["G","H","I"], ["J","K","L"]]
```

I know to shuffle a simple array, but this one is more complex and I tried many way, nothing works.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to shuffle it? Shuffling the subarrays or the letters within each subarrays?

Comment: I would like to shuffle the subarrays only, not the letters into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of questions on SO about shuffling array. The solution I personally use is a function provided by GameplayKit. You don't need to write a game to utilize it:

```
import GameplayKit

var answers = [["A","B","C"], ["D","E","F"], ["G","H","I"], ["J","K","L"]]
answers = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: answers) as! [[String]]
```